# how to create a subdomain in a dedicated apache2 server

Tags: linux, apache2, debian

I want to create a subdomain I followed this steps :

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
nano test.mydomaine.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
        ServerName  test.mydomaine.com
        ServerAlias www.test.mydomaine.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/testfolder/
<Directory "/var/www/testfolder">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "test"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/testfolder/passwords
        Require valid-user test
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

exit and save

```
a2ensite test.mydomaine.com
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

but It's not working am I missing something ?

Comment: In what manner is it "not working"? "Not working" means nothing by itself.

Comment: when I tape test.mydomaine.com in the borwser It gives nothing

Comment: Nothing? No error, no message, just an empty page?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: Erreur 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)also when I ping test.mydomain.com , it dosen't convert it to the ip of the site

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/74940/how-do-i-setup-sub-domain-for-apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work, you additionally have to configure DNS resolution for the new hostname `test.mydomain.com`.  If you are just playing with this locally and do not want to create a "real" DNS entry, you have to edit the file `/etc/hosts` so that your computer can resolve the hostname to an IP address.  If you are running the web server on the same machine as the browser, you will want to map `test.mydomain.com` to `127.0.0.1`.  If the browser is on a different machine on your local network, you'll need to determine the server's IP address and then on the *browser* machine, edit `/etc/hosts` to add the mapping.

On Windows, the file is called `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

A sample entry would be (for the browser running on the same machine as the server):

```
127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
```

If the server is at, say 192.168.0.5, the entry would be

```
192.168.0.5 test.mydomain.com
```

EDIT: If the server has a real routable IP address, then if you want the `test.mydomain.com` address to resolve on the global Internet you will have to get your service provider to add it to DNS.  For testing purposes, you can still use `/etc/hosts` as described above.  Just substitute the server's real IP instead of `127.0.0.1`.  Do this on the system where you are running the browser.

Comment: I'm not in a localhost , it's a real dedicated server with a domain , So How can I configure dns  for the new hostname ?